# Getting SQL syntax error inside condition which is not executing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am running a long SQL script and in which I am facing a issue regarding `"column not available"` from a condition which is `false`.
Flow is not going inside condition but still getting issue
Also tried with `SET NOEXEC ON` but still getting issues.

Comment: Include query and error details in your question.

Comment: Yes, in exactly the same way that most programming languages will report *syntax errors* during compilation, any *runtime* control flow is irrelevant. Why would you think SQL would behave differently?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Is there any way to skip some part of query from parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is being thrown at parse time, before even reaching execution. If there is a parse/validation error then nothing will execute as the SQL engine considers the code to be wrongly written.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Example') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Example

CREATE TABLE #Example (
    FirstColumn INT)
GO

IF 1 = 0 -- Always false
BEGIN

    SELECT
        C.NonExistantColumn
    FROM
        #Example AS C

END

--Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
--Invalid column name 'NonExistantColumn'.
```

You need to make sure that all your referencing columns exist when you send your batch to the server. An alternative would be executing your statement with Dynamic SQL (which the server won't parse until you execute it).

Comment: How do you know K.D. uses SQL Server?